# Создать CSV строку из списка, заменив последний разделитель на другую строку (например " and ")

Tags: python

Приветствую!
Я новичок в Python, знаю, что одну задачу можно решить многими способами, хотелось бы увидеть **изящные и интересные** решения следующей задачи:

Требуется написать функцию, которая принимает список в качестве аргумента и возвращает строку, в которой все элементы разделены запятой и пробелом, а перед последним элементом вставлено слово and. Например: если вводится список [aa, bb, cc, dd], то на выходе должно получиться 'aa, bb, cc and dd'

Я решил это так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def delim(spis):
  b = spis.split()
  x = ((' '.join(b[:-1])).split())
  print(', '.join(x) + ' and ' + str(b[-1]))
spis = delim(input('Input own list: '))
```

Comment: Ваша функция принимает строку и не возвращает ничего, вы не решили задачу

Comment: @andreymal она печатает результат, на мой взгляд, это тоже решение :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
def delim(lst, sep=', ', last_sep=' and '):
    return last_sep.join(sep.join(lst).rsplit(sep,1))
```

Примеры использования:

```
In [24]: l = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']

In [25]: delim(l)
Out[25]: 'aa, bb, cc and dd'

In [26]: delim(l, sep=',')
Out[26]: 'aa,bb,cc and dd'

In [27]: delim(l, last_sep=' but not ')
Out[27]: 'aa, bb, cc but not dd'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spis = ['a','b','c',100]
def anac(spis):
    a = ' ,'
    while True:
        q = str(spis[0]) + a
        b = str(spis[1]) + a
        c = str(spis[2]) + a
        d = 'and' + ' ' + str(spis[3])
        print(q, b, c, d)
        break

anac(spis)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]